# Is there a XSS injection vulnerability in PrimeFaces Slider?

Tags: security, primefaces, xss, code-injection

A scan on our Primefaces app came up with an XSS alert saying that this is an injection. It is a slider and the set method in the bean takes an int - so I do not think I can validate the input myself besides the fact that the set method takes an int.

Is this a true vulnerability or a false positive?
Is there a fix?

```
<tr><td><span id="j_id_20:forceUtcOutput">!slider.forceUtc.start!</span>    </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" id="j_id_20:forceUtc" name="j_id_20:forceUtc"     value="0--
&gt;&quot;;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;iframe src=javascript:alert(3714) " /></td>    </tr>
<tr><td><div id="j_id_20:j_id_2c" class="borderGrid"></div><script     id="j_id_20:j_id_2c_s"
type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("Slider","widget_j_id_20_j_id_2c",{id:"j_id_20:j_id_2c",value:"0-->";
</script><iframe src=javascript:alert(3714)
.... 
Template:"???slider.forceUtc???",display:"j_id_20:forceUtcOutput"});});
//--></script></td></tr>
```

The scanner replaced a 0 in the HTTP request with:

```
0-->";</script><iframe src=javascript:alert(3714)
```

Comment: I fail to understand this statement: _" so I do not think I can validate the input myself"_ Care to elaborate?

Comment: The bean method accepts an int. The scanner injects a string and the scanner's finding happens regardless of what makes it to the backing bean method,